# A sequence defined by setting $a_{n+1}$=$\frac{a_{n}^{p-1}+\frac{a}{a_{n}^{p-1}}}{p}$ Find $Lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $a_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question** For p$\in\mathbb{N}$, $a$$>$0 and $a_{1}>0$ define
>   the sequence $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} $by setting
>
> $a_{n+1}$=$\frac{a_{n}^{p-1}+\frac{a}{a_{n}^{p-1}}}{p}$ Find $Lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$a_{n}$

**My approach** Actually i can prove that the sequence is monotonically
decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt[p]{a}$

Book mentions the answer $\sqrt[p]{a}$

but i can not say that every monotonically decreasing sequence converges
to its lower bound .There can exist $l$ such that $l\geq$ $\sqrt[p]{a}$

and $Lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$a_{n}$= $l$. We can not be sure
about it

it would be wrong if i say $l$=${\sqrt[p]{a}}$

**My proof of lower bound** using AM $\geq$GM inequality

$\frac{A+B}{p}\geq$$\sqrt[p]{A.B}$

$a_{n+1}$$\geq$$\sqrt[p]{a^{p-1}\frac{a}{a^{p-1}}}$$\Longrightarrow$$a_{n+1}$$\geq$$\sqrt[p]{a}$

**Edit** Actually Real question in the book was $\Longrightarrow$ [image: This]

And its answer $\Longrightarrow$ [image: This]

I thought there is some misprinting in the book so i corrected it and asked the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: @asdf yes brother i know this theorem .it assures the convergence but do not says anything about the limit of the sequence

Comment: Well, no, it say that a bounded increasing (decreasing) sequence converges to its supremum (infimum)

Comment: @asdf i can not prove that $\sqrt[p]{n}$ is infimum attained by the sequence.I can only prove, it is bounded below. If you want i can show the proof

Comment: @asdf Thanks brother i got it

Comment: are you sure that answer is $a^{\frac{1}{p}}$?

Comment: @asdf i have added the proof

Comment: This shows that is is bounded below by that number, not that the infimum is this. It is also bounded below by $0$ but that doesn't imply that this is the limit

Comment: @asdf The relation is not greater than, The relation is greater or equal to ,so it is the infimum.the same thing i was also missing

Comment: See the answer for clarification for the AM-GM inequality

Comment: $\{ a_n\}$ is neither decreasing nor bounded.

Comment: @user32828 brother i have made an edit , i think you should check that

Comment: Question as well as solution in your book is correct. You have mistakenly thought that there is some error in the book. Books may have error but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Please explain this step of the book  $a_{n+1}$$\geq$$\sqrt[p]{a^{p-1}\frac{a}{a^{p-1}}}$. How the author  came to this step

Comment: This is just AM GM inequality with $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_{p-1}=a_{n},x_p=a/a_n^{p-1}$ and then use $$\frac {x_1+x_2+\dots+x_p}{p}\geq \sqrt[p] {x_1 x_2\dots x_p} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought it'd be a good idea to write the comment as an answer since I wasn't descriptive enough:

$1)$ Use Monotone Convergence Theorem: It says that  bounded increasing (decreasing) sequence converges to its supremum (infimum).

$2)$ You've shown that the sequence is monotone and bounded, hence the infimum exists, hence the limit exists.

$3)$ Let that limit be $l$. Since the limit of any subsequence of a convergent sequence is that same as the limit of the sequence itself, we get the following:

$$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n+1}$$

Hence using the definition of a sequence and taking limits of both sides we get the equation:

**Note: This equation is valid only for the formulation of the problem before the edit**
$$l=\frac{l^{p-1}+\frac{a}{l^{p-1}}}{p}$$

I suppose you can solve this, if not, I can be of assistance

The problem is your AM-GM: you have the sum of only $2$ things:

Hence $$a_{n+1}p=a_n^{p-1}+\frac{a}{a_n^{p-1}} \geq 2\sqrt{a}$$ 
hence $a_{n+1}\geq \frac{2\sqrt{a}}{p}$

Comment: Yes brother thank you

Comment: AM-GM Inequality is true for all values greater than 2 as well.Check it yourself

Comment: All, I'm saying is that your lower bound is wrong: Take $p=4,a=1,a_1=1$. Then $a_2=\frac{1}{2}<1^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Comment: And your edit is wrong: $\frac{1+1}{3}<(1\cdot1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! And no, $\frac{2}{3}<1$

Comment: The AM-GM for $2$ non-negative real number says that $\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$ In my case,$\frac{1+1}{2}\geq \sqrt{1\cdot 1}$ is true and we have equality

Comment: $a_{n+1}p=a_{n}^{p-1}+\frac{a}{a_{n}^{p-1}}\geq2\sqrt{a}$ Explain this bro.How did you get 2$\sqrt{a}$

Comment: This is AM-GM:  $\frac{a_n^{p-1}+\frac{a}{a_n^{p-1}}}{2} \geq \sqrt{a_n^{p-1}\cdot\frac{a}{a_n^{p-1}}}=\sqrt{a}$