# Find$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{n+\sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n+\cos\left(n\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

> **Question** Find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n+\sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n+\cos\left(n\right)}$$

**My Approach** $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n+\sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n+cos\left(n\right)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{n}{n+\cos\left(n\right)}+\frac{\sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n+\cos n}\right]
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{\cos\left(n\right)}{n}}+\frac{\sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n+\cos n}\right]$$

Applying L ' Hospital is not working here

Comment: Because its not $0/0$ form! Simply divide by $n$ on numerator and denominator and split the limit on numerator and denominator. You have the limit as $1$.

Comment: @SamjoeThanks  i am gonna try it. Brother there is one more question i posted it yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590230/a-sequence-defined-by-setting-a-n1-fraca-np-1-fracaa-np-1

Comment: @samjoe lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n}$ is it
Intermediate Form or lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n}$=
0 ?

Comment: I think you mean *Indeterminate*. Well this is not and yes indeed $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n} = 0$. Note that numerator always lies between $-1$ and $1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin^2(n)}{n+\cos(n)}-1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2(n)-\cos(n)}{n+\cos(n)}=0,$$since the numerator is bounded and the denominator tends to $+\infty$. Therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin^2(n)}{n+\cos(n)}=1.$$

Comment: Thanks .  there is one more question i posted it yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590230/a-sequence-defined-by-setting-a-n1-fraca-np-1-fracaa-np-1

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin^2(n)}{n+\cos(n)}$-1 Did you use any theorem .Why did you used -1 ?

Comment: @MohanSharma None. SInce both the numerator and the denominator behaved as $n$ when $n\gg1$, the limit had to be $1$. I justified that by proving that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin^2(n)}{n+\cos(n)}-1=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Observes that 
$$\frac{n+\sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n+\cos\left(n\right)}=\frac{1+\frac{\sin(n^{2})}{n}}{1+\frac{\cos(n )}{n})} \to 1$$

Since $$\frac{\sin(n^{2})}{n} \to0~~~and ~~~\frac{\cos(n)}{n} \to0$$

Comment: lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n}$ is it
Intermediate Form or lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{sin\left(n^{2}\right)}{n}$=
0 ?

Comment: @MohanSharma Yes of course see the edit